# What is best practise for testing whether a method is supported on an interface and call it?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Say I have 2 interfaces, which follow the same sequence of function calls.

The 1st interface has an extra method on it, the 2nd has no method so should not be called.  How do I test whether the method is supported and then call it?

Is it best to cast the object to the interface, and if not null then call the method or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you checking types in the code that uses these two interfaces?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice i know is:

```
myInterface myCastedObject = myObject as myInterface;
if(myCastedObject != null)
{
   myCastedObject.myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the `is` operator and interfaces are intended for.

```
if (obj1 is MyInterface1)
   (obj1 as MyInterface1).Method1();
```

Comment: But this checks the type twice.  Using `as` plus a null check avoids that.

Comment: @phoog: you are right but I don't micro-optimize unless there is a good reason.

Comment: @Henk - Clarity isn't 'micro-optimizing'.

Comment: @RitchMelton And where is the clarity in the as+null approach?

Comment: @Henk- Although your example is small, in normal methods where the object is acted on several times, casting an interface over and over adds noise to a method's intent. Casting it once into a local with as makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `is` is to utilize the fact that `as` returns `null` if the cast fails:

```
var casted = obj as MyInterface1;
if (casted != null)
    casted.Method1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keywork to check is and object is the interface you wish to use.

```
if(myObject is myInterface) 
{
   ((myInterface)myObject).myMethod();
}
```

Comment: This won't work when the interface is explicitly implemented or when myObject1 is of a base-type.

Comment: @Baboon unless the static type of myObject has a public myMethod method.  (Granted, in that case, it wouldn't make much sense to ask the question in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the extended interface to inherit from the first, you can create two methods that explicitly call what they should with no repeated code.

```
public interface IFirst
{ ... }

public interface ISecond : IFirst
{ ... }

public void DoWork(IFirst obj) {...}

public void DoWork(ISecond obj)
{
    DoWork(obj as IFirst);

    /* ISecond calls */
}
```

In this model, *you* aren't checking types.